# Error : x = (x * 255).astype(np.uint8) in python matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

.......

fig.savefig(outfilename)
```

is giving the following error.

> File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/image.py", line 211, in
>   _get_unsampled_image
>       x = (x * 255).astype(np.uint8) MemoryError

Could any one explain what is the problem.